# How do I go through a database in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a database composed of symptoms of a disease and the disease to which these symptoms belongs as follows.

```
disease([dordecabeca,febre,dormuscular,dorgarganta,cansaco],gripe).
disease([febre,dordecabeca,dorolhos,manchas,nauseas],dengue).
disease([febre,coceira,dordecabeca,dordebarriga,perdadeapetite],catapora).
disease([febre,dordecabeca,fadiga,perdadeapetite,inchacorosto],caxumba).
disease([congestaonasal,gargantairritada,espirros,febre,tosse],resfriado).

treatment([evitarmedicamentosdeaspirina,respouso],dengue).
treatment([evitarmedicamentosdeaspirina,repouso,paracetamol],dengue).
treatment([repouso,evitarpessoas,semmedicamento],catapora).
treatment([repouso,evitarpessoas,medicamento],catapora).
treatment([repouso,evitarpessoas],caxumba).
treatment([repouso,boaalimentacao],gripe).
treatment([repouso,boalimentacao,medicamentos],gripe).
treatment([repouso,boaalimentacao,semmedicamentos],refriado).
treatment([repouso,boaalimentacao,medicamento],resfriado).

symptoms(L1,X):-disease(L1,X).
treatdisease(L1,L2,Y):-symptoms(L1,Y),treatment(L2,Y).
```

With the symptons predicate, I can visualize all the symptoms and the corresponding disease. And with the predicate treatdisease, I can see the treatment based on the disease common to the two bases.

```
symptoms(L1,X):-disease(L1,X).
treatdisease(L1,L2,Y):-symptoms(L1,Y),treatment(L2,Y).
```

But what if I were to compare an entry list with the underlying disease like I would?
If it was just a list I already have the predicate, but on a multidimensional basis I have no idea how to go.

For example if I came in with:

```
  ?searchdisease([dordecabeca,febre,dormuscular,dorgarganta],Disease).
```

How do I go through the bases using this list with the database?

So I have predicates to pick up the different elements between two lists and a predicate to get the equal elements between two lists, but I do not know how to use them when the list is in a subset. Follow the predicates.

```
%---------------------------------------------------------
%Predicate to pick up equal elements between two lists.

equalelements([],[]).
equalelements([X|Xs0],Ys0) :-
   tpartition(=(X),Xs0,Es,Xs),
   if_(Es=[], Ys0=Ys, Ys0=[X|Ys]),
   equalelements(Xs,Ys).

tpartition(P_2,List,Ts,Fs) :-
   tpartition_ts_fs_(List,Ts,Fs,P_2).

tpartition_ts_fs_([],[],[],_).
tpartition_ts_fs_([X|Xs0],Ts,Fs,P_2) :-
   if_(call(P_2,X), (Ts = [X|Ts0], Fs = Fs0),
                (Ts = Ts0,     Fs = [X|Fs0])),
   tpartition_ts_fs_(Xs0,Ts0,Fs0,P_2).

if_(If_1, Then_0, Else_0) :-
   call(If_1, T),
   (  T == true -> call(Then_0)
   ;  T == false -> call(Else_0)
   ;  nonvar(T) -> throw(error(type_error(boolean,T),_))
   ;  /* var(T) */ throw(error(instantiation_error,_))
   ).

=(X, Y, T) :-
   (  X == Y -> T = true
   ;  X \= Y -> T = false
   ;  T = true, X = Y
   ;  T = false,
      dif(X, Y)                             % ISO extension
   % throw(error(instantiation_error,_)) % ISO strict
   ).

equal_t(X, Y, T):-
   =(X, Y, T).
%------------------------------------------------------------
%Predicate to pick up different elements between two lists. 

displaydifference([],[],[]).
displaydifference(L1,L2,L4):-concatenate(L1,L2,L3), remove_dups(L3,L4).

concatenate(L1, L2, NL) :-
   append(L1, L2, L12),
   msort(L12, NL).

remove_dups([], []).
remove_dups([X], [X]).
remove_dups([X,Y|T], [X|R]) :-
   X \= Y,
   remove_dups([Y|T], R).
remove_dups([X,X|T], R) :-
   skip(X, T, WithoutX),
   remove_dups(WithoutX, R).

skip(_,[],[]).
skip(X, [X|T], T).
skip(X, [Y|T], [Y|T]) :- X \= Y.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to understand what do you exactly want obtain with `searchdisease/2`.

I suppose that you want a predicate that, given a list of symptoms, unifies the second parameter with one or more diseases with symptoms that are a superset of the first parameter.

In that case, I propose

```
subList([], _).

subList([H | T], S) :-
  member(H, S),
  subList(T, S).

searchdisease(Symptoms, Disease) :-
  disease(Ls, Disease),
  subList(Symptoms, Ls).
```

If you call `searchdisease([dordecabeca,febre,dormuscular,dorgarganta],Disease)`, you unify `Disease` with `gripe` because `[dordecabeca,febre,dormuscular,dorgarganta]` is a subset of the symptoms of `gripe`.

If you call `searchdisease([febre],D)`, you unify `D` with `gripe` and, trying again with backtracking, `dengue`, `catapora`, `caxumba` and `resfriado`, because `febre` is a symptom of all of this five diseases.

En passant: I don't understand the usefulness of `symptoms/2`; why don't you simply use `disease/2`?

Comment: So I want to be able to compare the list I get with all the list in the database, you know? My goal is to compare the list of entries with all the lists, but not always the lists will be the same, that is, I will go comparing until I find the correct disease for the corresponding symptom independent of the order of the symptoms.

Comment: @AndersonMendes you need to define *compare*. Subset? Has a non-empty intersection? Has identical set of elements?...

Comment: @lurker That's almost it, I made changes to the scope.

Comment: max66 was amused by his predicate, now I understand how it works to walk between the sublists. Thank you.